# Authorize.net setup in backend but doesn't appear on checkout pages

Tags: authorize.net

I’ve setup and enabled the authorize.net payment gateway in the backend; but it doesn’t appear on the frontend during checkout. I’ve double checked all of the info that l’ve put into the admin panel and all of the information is correct.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

DUH! We had the wrong store view selected -- ouch sorry to waste everyone's time!